# On router.replace, prevent changing to top scroll position

Tags: vue-router, nuxtjs3

I am using `useRouter`, and when I want to change the current URL with `router.replace`, the scroll position goes to the top. How can I prevent that?

It doesn't happen if I try the "`history.replaceState`" from the history API.

**Scroll position changes to top:**

```
if (process.client) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    router.replace('?thing=ok');
  }, 4000);
}
```

**Scroll position stays unchanged:**

```
if (process.client) {
  setTimeout(() => {
     history.replaceState(null, null, '?thing=ok');
  }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
router.replace('?thing=ok', '', { scroll: false );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?